# Mapserver map file reading WMTS and serving WMS?

Tags: wms, mapserver, wmts

I need to create a Mapserver map file that would read maps from (external) WMTS interface and serve them as WMS.

How should I get started? Could anyone link to useful instructions or give an example?

Comment: You seem to have two questions, one is how to cascade a wmts through MapServer.  The other is whether there is any benefit in doing so.

Comment: Thanks for comment, nmtoken. I edited my post slightly since the other question was actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

The connection to the WMTS is made through the [service configuration XML file](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html)  of GDAL, which can be obtained through the following command:

```
gdal_translate http://serviciosgis.catastrobogota.gov.co/arcgis/rest/services/Mapa_Reference/map_base_3857/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml wmts.xml -of WMTS
```

As a result you get the following file:

```
<GDAL_WMTS>
  <GetCapabilitiesUrl>http://serviciosgis.catastrobogota.gov.co/arcgis/rest/services/Mapa_Referencia/mapa_base_3857/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml</GetCapabilitiesUrl>
  <Layer>Mapa_Referencia_mapa_base_3857</Layer>
  <Style>default</Style>
  <TileMatrixSet>default028mm</TileMatrixSet>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-8530516.724611044</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>787485.3238264732</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>-7912313.895742185</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>171205.2146587537</LowerRightY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
  <Cache />
  <UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
  <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
  <ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
</GDAL_WMTS>
```

I recommend verifying that this file can be loaded as a raster layer in the QGIS software.

Once, you can do the configuration in the Mapfile and specify the connection through the GDAL driver, here is a mapfile example:

```
MAP
  DEFRESOLUTION 96
  EXTENT -8251807.87026254 515749.224663909 -8244059.40876483 520717.918565494
  IMAGETYPE "png24"
  NAME "MAPA_REFERENCIA"
  RESOLUTION 96
  SHAPEPATH ""
  SIZE 1378 884
  STATUS ON
  UNITS METERS

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "png24"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    TRANSPARENT FALSE
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "print"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    TRANSPARENT FALSE
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:3857"
  END # PROJECTION
  LEGEND
    KEYSIZE 20 10
    KEYSPACING 5 5
    LABEL
      SIZE 10
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
    END # LABEL
    STATUS OFF
  END # LEGEND

  QUERYMAP
    SIZE -1 -1
    STATUS OFF
    STYLE HILITE
  END # QUERYMAP

  SCALEBAR
    INTERVALS 4
    LABEL
      SIZE 10
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
    END # LABEL
    SIZE 200 3
    STATUS OFF
    UNITS MILES
  END # SCALEBAR

  WEB
    METADATA
      "distance_units"      "MS_METERS"
      "mapmanager_version"  "1.0.0.0"
      "wms_title"           "IDECA Mapa de Referencia"
      "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.fcgi?map=/srv/http/mapfiles/ideca.map"
      "wms_srs"             "EPSG:3857 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3116"
      "wms_enable_request"  "*"   ##necessary
      "wms_contactperson"   "Samuel Mesa"
      "wms_contactorganization" "Universidad Nacional de Colombia - Sede Bogota"
      "wms_contactposition" "Profesor"
    END # METADATA
  END # WEB

  LAYER
    COMPOSITE
    END # COMPOSITE
    DATA "./wmts.xml"
    EXTENT -8530516.72461104 171205.214658754 -7912313.89574219 787485.323826473
    METADATA
      "coordsys_name" "Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator (deprecated)"
      "wms_title"    "Mapa Referencia"   ##required
    END # METADATA
    NAME "mapa_referencia"
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:3857"
    END # PROJECTION
    STATUS ON
    TILEITEM "location"
    TYPE RASTER
    UNITS METERS
  END # LAYER

END # MAP
```

Finally, the WMS service connection is tested on the GIS client of your choice.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.fcgi?map=/srv/http/mapfiles/ideca.map&Service=WMS&Request=GetCapabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

[SamTux's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276427/26159) has a very complete example on serving WMTS layers with MapServer.  You can also serve the layer directly by pointing the `DATA` to the WMTS Capabilities endpoint of the WMTS layer:

```
LAYER
    NAME cascaded_wmts_layer
    TYPE RASTER
    DATA "http://serviciosgis.catastrobogota.gov.co/arcgis/rest/services/Mapa_Reference/map_base_3857/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml"
    STATUS OFF

    PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:3857"
    END
END
```

[Mapfile layer DATA](https://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html#mapfile-layer-data) can be [nearly anything readable by GDAL](https://mapserver.org/input/raster.html#supported-formats).   To tell if something is readable by GDAL you can just run `gdalinfo __file_or_url__`, like so:

```
gdalinfo http://serviciosgis.catastrobogota.gov.co/arcgis/rest/services/Mapa_Referencia/mapa_base_3857/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

*AFAIK* it is not directly possible to use an WMTS as an input data source in MapServer (unlike WMS).  You will need to work out how to convert the input into a supported [GDAL raster format](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html).  I don't think it's covered by the [GDAL WMS format driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).  It might be something that could be configured as a [VRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html)

Comment: You could do this using a recent version of GeoServer